# Most sensitive device made by humans

Tags: technology

I am not sure this question belongs on Physics SE, but I couldn't think of a better SE. My question is, what is the most sensitive device made by humans? Could it be LIGO, the gravitational wave detector?

Comment: You need to define sensitivity fairly which you can't really across multiple types of measuremennts. Would be more answerable if you chose just one type of measurement.

Comment: I still think LIGO is a good candidate though.